# Which data type in Racket is this?

Tags: scheme, racket, type-conversion

For example:

```
'(ace spade king queen)
```

I understand it's in a list but i'm not sure what data type that would be.. I'm assuming it's a string but isn't a string supposed to have double quotations around the word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a list of *symbols* (not strings). It's the same as this:

```
(list 'ace 'spade 'king 'queen)
```

For more details please check the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html). Notice that a list of strings would look like this:

```
'("ace" "spade" "king" "queen")
```

Or equivalently:

```
(list "ace" "spade" "king" "queen")
```